# return random dictionary items in swift

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, io, tuples

I'm trying to return a random name and a random email from this function have got so far but I'm wondering what should I be returning here obviously as I want to return a tuple it needs to be 2 string values which I need randomly from my function

```
func randomAuthor () -> (name : String, email : String) {

    struct Author {

        var name : String
        var email : String

    }

    let firstAuthor = Author(name: "jon", email: "jonsEmail")
    let secondAuthor = Author(name: "richard", email: "richardsEmail")
    let thirdAuthor = Author(name: "steve", email: "stevesEmail")
    let fourthAuthor = Author(name: "simon", email: "simonsEmail")
    let fifthAtouh = Author(name: "wes", email: "wesEmail")

    var dictionary = [firstAuthor.name : firstAuthor.email, secondAuthor.name : secondAuthor.email, thirdAuthor.name : thirdAuthor.email, fourthAuthor.name : fourthAuthor.email, fifthAuthor.name : fithAtouh.email]

    var unsignedDictionaryCount = UInt32(dictionary.count)
    var unsignedRandom = arc4random_uniform(unsignedDictionaryCount)
    var random = unsignedRandom


    return()

}
```

any help appreciated
thanks

Comment: Better use an array instead of a dictionary, then use the random index to get one of the array elements...

Comment: thanks needs to specifically be a dictionary unfortunately any other thoughts on how to do this with what I have?  thanks

Comment: Get a random index. Use that index to get the object in the dictionary's `allKeys`. Then you can get the value from that random key.

Comment: let index: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(dictionary.count)) something like this? how do I return 2 string though via my tuple return type any ideas?   thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random value from an Dictionary in several steps:

1. Create your Dictionary
2. Get a random `Int` using `arc4random_uniform`
3. Used this random `Int` to get a random key (using `keys`), and get its value
4. Return them, and you are done !

   ```
   var dictionary : [String:String] =  [firstAuthor.name : firstAuthor.email, secondAuthor.name : secondAuthor.email, thirdAuthor.name : thirdAuthor.email, fourthAuthor.name : fourthAuthor.email]
   let index: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(dictionary.count)))
   let value = Array(dictionary.values)[index]
   let key = Array(dictionary.keys)[index]
   let value = dictionary[key]
   return (key, value!)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use your random integer as an index into `dictionary.keys`. This will fetch you the `name` that you can use to look up your `email`.